# How to plot a time evolution with ggplot in R with year on x-axis as integer?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, time

I want to plot the time evolution for the variable lending per capita. The data in column "year" is numeric, so I've added a new column to my data frame named "yearint" where I convert year from numeric to integer. Unfortunately, the x-axis still shows years with a decimal place (see image). I just want to have the year without any decimal place on the x-axis. How can I do this?

```
#adding a new column to my data frame for "year" as an integer
myDataframe$yearint <- as.integer(myDataframe$year)

#creating a plot
myPlot <- group_by(myDataframe, yearint) %>% summarize(myVariablePlot = mean(myVariable))
timeEvolution <- ggplot(myPlot, aes(x = yearint, y = myVariablePlot)) + xlim(2009,2019) + geom_point(size=3) + geom_line(color = "steelblue") + labs(x = "Year", y = "Average log lending per capita") + ggtitle("Time evolution for lending")
print(timeEvolution)
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of `xlim` use `scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2009:2019)`. If you want the years more spaced, say by increments of 2, use `breaks = seq(2009, 2019, by = 2)`

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick and easy solution. It works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we don't have your original data, I'll use the `gapminder` dataset from the `gapminder` package to demonstrate.

First take a look at `df`, we can confirm the year column is of type integer (`<int>`).

```r
library(gapminder)
library(tidyverse)

df <- filter(gapminder::gapminder, country == "Afghanistan")

df
# A tibble: 12 × 6
   country     continent  year lifeExp      pop gdpPercap
   <fct>       <fct>     <int>   <dbl>    <int>     <dbl>
 1 Afghanistan Asia       1952    28.8  8425333      779.
 2 Afghanistan Asia       1957    30.3  9240934      821.
```

Then plot the data. Here we need `scale_x_continuous`. To achieve what you want, you need to set both `limits` and `breaks`. To mimic your graph, I've set `breaks` to every two years with `limits` of ten years.

```
ggplot(df, aes(year, lifeExp)) + 
  geom_point(size=3) + 
  geom_line(color = "steelblue") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1952, 1962), breaks = seq(1952, 1962, 2))
```

[image: scale_x_continuous_limits_breaks]